# Checkpoint table does not exist even after creating it

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I have created checkpoint table ggate for replicat rep1 but still I am getting following error:

> 2014-09-04 23:38:21  ERROR   OGG-00446  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for
>   Oracle, REP1.prm:  Checkpoint table ggate.checkpoint does not exist. 
>   Please create the table or recreate the REP1 group using the correct
>   table.
>
> 2014-09-04 23:38:21  ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for
>   Oracle, REP1.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situations you should:

1. Have you actually run the ADD CHECKPOINTTABLE? if not run it
2. Check if the checkpoint table actually exists in the database - if it has been created - try to drop it (DROP CHECKPOINTTABLE) and recreate it (ADD CHECKPOINTTABLE)
3. Check if the checkpoint parameter is correctly set in the GLOBALS config file
4. Restart the MGR and Extract/Replicat processes
5. Verify if the user has access on the database to the checkpoint table (insert, update, delete rights)
6. If nothing works, run 10046 flag on the target database and check what the GoldenGate Replicat process is executing on the database and when it actually fails (what it wants to do on the database and try to do the same commands by yourself)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple troubleshooting initiative:

1. Are you using a traditional non-CDB database or a PDB?
2. Are you using Classic Architecture or Microservices Architecture? - Different approaches when adding a checkpoint table.
3. How are you running ADD CHECKPOINTTABLE?  From GGSCI/AdminClient or from HTML5 page?
4. In Classic Architecture, do you have CHECKPOINTTABLE parameter set in GLOBALS? (CHECKPOINTTABLE [container.] owner.table)
5. Who are you logged into the database as when using DBLOGIN USERIDALIAS?
6. What replicat are you using? - Classic, Coordinated, Integrated, Parallel?
7. Check the schema where the table is suppose to be?  If not there, you can query the DBA_TABLES view for the name of the checkpoint table and see who owns it.

A lot of times when the checkpint table cannot be created it is due to not updating the GLOBALS file and/or connecting as the correct user to the database.